# pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX in a Miktex configuration

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, line, appendix

I am a beginner and in my document (book class) I have a ToC in which I have included the appendices. I have two questions:

1. in the ToC there are no dots to the page number in the Part-references, but there are dots to the page number in the Chapter-references - I want this to be so. But I similarly want to omit the dots also in the line that says "Appendices", while now they appear;
2. the appendices appear in the ToC, but the line spacing is not ok - the entries even overlap! - while the spacing in the rest of the ToC is perfect.
   Can anyone help me?
   Thank you very much in advance
   Rik

Here are the declarations in my .tex

```
\usepackage{amssymb} %voor de genormaliseerde wiskundige aspecten

\usepackage{amsmath} %voor de genormaliseerde wiskundige aspecten

\usepackage{amsfonts} %voor de genormaliseerde wiskundige aspecten

\usepackage {mathrsfs} %voor de genormaliseerde wiskundige aspecten

\usepackage[dutch]{babel} %voor Nederlandse titulatuur

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} %voor schikking van formules

\usepackage{tikz} %voor tekeningen en grafieken

\usepackage{lipsum,pgffor,sectsty} %voor lettertypes en lettergroottes

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\setlength\cftparskip{-7pt}

\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{0pt}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{0pt}

\renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{3em} %scheiding tussen nummers en titel

\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %puntjes naar blz

\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}%Deel font in ToC

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\large\itshape}    %Hoofdstuk font in ToC

\appendix

\appendixpage

\addappheadtotoc

\begin{appendices}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}

\section{Een excursie in $ \mathscr{S}=\{3n-2: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}\}$}

In oefening 4.10 etc etc

\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
\section{Een andere excursie in $ \mathscr{S}=\{3n-2: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}\}$}

In oefening 4.11 ...

\end{appendices}
```